# XAML: Expanding a 'dynamic resource' using a static one

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a combo box, where it's style taken from a dynamic resource file, using the DynamicResource  key word.

Now, I want to add a specific style to the combo box on the current specific view containing the combo box, let's say a trigger for setting enable \ disable or visibility etc.

How can I combine the usage of the dynamic resource and the static one?

Comment: First, why would you do such a thing? Means, what's the desired effect on the UI? Second, how is this `MVVM` related?

Comment: Can you not use `StaticResource` instead of `DynamicResource`? then you can do BasedOn.

Comment: The case is that I have a combo with a dynamic resource written by an external xaml developer; I need to use it as a dynamic resource, and want to add a specific style of my own in the view where I use the combo: I want it to be disabled, if it's selected item is null. I want it to happen only in MY view, so I don't want to change dynamic resource.